# php $_get variable gone after submitting form

Tags: php, mysql, html, database

my problem goes like this:
my home page has tables with rows pulled from the database (while loops)
each row has a  - cell in which he can add an event to that specific row 
in order to do that i send the row id as a $_GET variable from the home page table
and in the "add event" page i store it as a variable
but when i submit my addevent form without filling it properly (as i coded) it simply refreshes the form only without the row id in the url therefor also the query i do in the beginning of the page for pulling the row data can no longer execute and that pops a PHP error 
for the id variable which i sign it the $_GET and the query (mysql fetch array).
also of course all the data which i display in the form from that query is gone.

any suggestions on how to approach this ? thanks in advance, Regards.

EDIT:** kill the new guy! -Sorry i guess

home page where i send the id :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM alarms WHERE alarmstatus = 'OFF' and starttime='::' ORDER BY clientid ASC";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<table cellpadding='1px' border='1px' bordercolor='#0066FF' cellspacing='0'>
        <form action='hpage.php' method='get'>";
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo "<tr>
            <td>
            ".$fetch['clientid']."</td>
            <td>".$fetch['controller']."</td>
            <td>".$fetch['typeid']."</td>
            <td style='color: red'>".$fetch['alarmstatus']."</td>
            <td>".$fetch['starttime']."</td>
            <td>".$fetch['endtime']."</td>
            <td><a href='includes/editalarm.php?id=".$fetch['id']."'>Edit</a></td>
            <td><a href='includes/addevent.php?id=".$fetch['id']."'>Add event</a></td>
            <td><a href='includes/deletealarm.php?id=".$fetch['id']."'>Delete</a></td>
    </tr>";
}
```

the add event where i get the variable and make the query:

```
$alarmid = $_GET['id'];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM alarms WHERE id=".$alarmid;
  $query = mysql_query($sql);
  $fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query);
?>
```

the form:

```
<table cellpadding="2px" cellspacing="0" >
 <form action="addevent.php" method="post">
   <tr>
     <td>סניף:</td>
     <td><input style="width:200px; background-color: #d6d6d6;" readonly name="client" value="<?php echo $fetch['clientid']; ?>" /></td>
   </tr> 
   <tr>
     <td>בקר:</td>
     <td><input style="width:200px; background-color: #d6d6d6;" readonly name="controller" value="<?php echo $fetch['controller']; ?>" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>אזעקה:</td>
     <td><input style="width:200px; background-color: #d6d6d6;" readonly name="controller" value="<?php echo $fetch['typeid']; ?>" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>מוקדן:</td>
     <td>
       <?php 
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE privilege = '2'";
       $query = mysql_query($sql);
       echo "<select name='user' style='width:207px;'>";
       echo "<option>..</option>";
       while ($fetch2 = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
         echo "<option>".$fetch2['username']."</option>";
       }
       echo "</select>";
       ?>       
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>איש קשר:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="contact" /></td>

   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>הודעה:</td>
     <td><input type="text" style="width:200px; height:100px" name="message" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>תשובה:</td>
     <td><input type="text" style="width:200px; height:100px" name="answer" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>שעה:</td>
     <td>
       <select name="eventhour">
         <option value ="default"></option>         
         <?php
           for($i = 0; $i<60; $i++){
             $value = $i;
             if($i<=9){
               $value= "0".$i;
             } 
           echo "<option>".$value."</option>";
           }
         ?>
       </select>  
       <select name="eventminute">
         <option value ="default"></option>
         <?php
           for($i = 0; $i<24; $i++){
             $value = $i;
             if($i<=9){
               $value= "0".$i;
             } 
           echo "<option>".$value."</option>";
           }
         ?>
       </select>         
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>  
       <input type="submit" name="save" value="שמור" />
       <input type="submit" name="cancell" value="בטל" />
     </td>
     <td></td>
   </tr>
 </form>
```

Comment: Could you produce some code? And please post the exact error

Comment: -1 for not providing the code. It's much easier to understand the code than read the whole paragraph you wrote.

Comment: When you build the form, add the get parameter to the action like `action="script.php?id=$_GET['id']"`, or use a hidden form element with the id, unless you're talking about something else.

Comment: Marcus Adams - Righteous in Sodom, thank u very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Your form action is POST. If you change that to GET then you will have the form as $_GET.